# swift_class_getInstanceExtents doesn't appear in XCode - how do you call it?

Tags: swift

Anyone know how you call:

```
swift_class_getInstanceExtents
```

Its in:

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Builtin.swift

But doesn't show in XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe Groff on swift-users answered this question for me. You add:

```
@_silgen_name("swift_class_getInstanceExtents") func swift_class_getInstanceExtents(theClass: AnyClass) -> (negative: UInt, positive: UInt)
```

To your file and then you can call swift_class_getInstanceExtents.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

Other methods in that open source Swift file are declared as explicitly `public` or `internal`, so I'm thinking that an undecorated function declaration like "`swift_class_getInstanceExtents`" is likely to not be publicly available.

Also, I found this intriguing blog post, which states ["the Builtin module in swift is actually only available to stdlib and not normal Swift programs"](http://ankit.im/swift/2016/01/12/swift-mysterious-builtin-module/) (which I'm guessing is what you are trying to do here).